# Relative path issue of htc file in stylesheet

Tags: css, styles, stylesheet

I have a style.css file where I am using the following style.

```
* {
*behavior: url('~boxsizing.htc');
```

}

Here boxsizing.htc is located in the project dir. When I use this style.css it does not call this file. However I have also used the following code also

```
    * {
    *behavior: url('http://wwww.mysite.com/boxsizing.htc');
}
```

I am able to open the file directory from the url http://wwww.mysite.com/boxsizing.htc. Would you please let me know how to call this file.

Comment: did you tried `url('boxsizing.htc');`

Comment: or `url('/boxsizing.htc');`?

Comment: Yes, I have used both the urls.

Answer (score 2):

you've probably found the answer to this by now, but for anyone else who is looking for it here you go...

The URL to the HTC file must be relative to your HTML(!) document, not relative to your CSS.

So use an absolute path, from the site root like this:

if these are your paths

```
htc file location: http://www.mysite.com/scripts/boxsizing.htc
```

and

```
css location: http://www.mysite.com/css/style.css
```

link in css like this:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
     *behavior: url(/scripts/boxsizing.htc);
}
```

link to documentation is here:
https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill